# How to create Digital XML Signatures using keypair algorithm "RSASSA-PSS" with Java?

Tags: java, xml, cryptography, digital-signature

I need to sign XML in Java using Digital Signatures.

I have a key pair using signature algorithm RSASSA-PSS:

- SunRsaSign RSASSA-PSS private CRT key, 2048 bits
- Sun RSASSA-PSS public key, 2048 bits

See this code here from the OpenJDK test framework: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/test/lib/jdk/test/lib/security/XMLUtils.java

I'm using this utility to load the value:

```
    Document doc = XMLUtils.string2doc("<a><b>Text</b>Raw</a>");
    KeyPairGenerator instance = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSASSA-PSS");
    instance.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair keyPair = instance.generateKeyPair();

    PSSParameterSpec pspec = new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-384", "MGF1",
            MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA512, 48, TRAILER_FIELD_BC);

    Document signed = XMLUtils.signer(keyPair.getPrivate(), keyPair.getPublic())
            .dm(DigestMethod.SHA384)
            .sm(SignatureMethod.RSA_PSS, new RSAPSSParameterSpec(pspec))
            .sign(doc);
    System.out.println(XMLUtils.doc2string(signed));

    System.out.println("Good? " + XMLUtils.validator().validate(signed, keyPair.getPublic()));
```

Unfortunately, this is not working

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyException: unsupported key algorithm: RSASSA-PSS
    at java.xml.crypto/org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(DOMKeyInfoFactory.java:85)
```

because:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.xml.crypto/share/classes/org/jcp/xml/dsig/internal/dom/DOMKeyInfoFactory.java#L82

```
@Override
public KeyValue newKeyValue(PublicKey key)  throws KeyException {
    String algorithm = key.getAlgorithm();
    if ("DSA".equals(algorithm)) {
        return new DOMKeyValue.DSA((DSAPublicKey) key);
    } else if ("RSA".equals(algorithm)) {
        return new DOMKeyValue.RSA((RSAPublicKey) key);
    } else if ("EC".equals(algorithm)) {
        return new DOMKeyValue.EC((ECPublicKey) key);
    } else {
        throw new KeyException("unsupported key algorithm: " + algorithm);
    }
}
```

It does not allow "RSASSA-PSS".

It appears that if it were to be changed to:

```
        } else if ("RSASSA-PSS".equals(algorithm) || "RSA".equals(algorithm)) {
            return new DOMKeyValue.RSA((RSAPublicKey) key);
```

That appears to work? Or maybe it just looks like it's working.

If this were changed `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")` that also works but then it wouldn't be the algorithm that I need.

Here is a recent change to the JDK related to this:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/8dbf7aa1#diff-fa025c90d09b130fe3a8da89b4ebc5fc3ec157ded54b858dabe8241d383880abR66

I notice that they convert the public key into a "self certificate" before using it in the XML signature.

`X509Certificate cert = g.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=Me"), 100);`

Those classes aren't public to Java so I can't use them. What is this doing exactly?

How do I properly sign an XML Signature using the RSASSA-PSS algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `KeyPairGenerator`, the [*SunRsaSign*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-17E3589E-E4BA-4881-9B12-9880DD2D128D) provider associates the generated RSA keys with the OID [*rsaEncryption*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017.html#appendix-A.1) (for `getInstance("RSA")`) and [*rsassa-pss*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017.html#appendix-A.2.3) (for `getInstance("RSASSA-PSS")`). The former generally identifies a (private or public) RSA key, the latter more specifically a key that is intended for signing with the RSASSA-PSS scheme.

However, the OID only specifies the context of the RSA key, technically the keys do not differ, e.g. in principle a public *rsassa-pss* key could be used for *rsaes-oaep* encryption. For security reasons, however, the keys should be used consistently with the OID.

For this reason, it is also possible for RSASSA-PSS to use `getInstance("RSA")` instead of `getInstance("RSASSA-PSS")` for key derivation and the existing implementation of the library is sufficient. The [test cases](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/40708baf7a5ad4a847f1b6414eda6a2ea4439d7e/test/jdk/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/PSSSpec.java#L138) of the library, which also use `getInstance("RSA")` for key generation, even show that this is the intended method.

Since the OID does not technically determine the algorithm or padding, this must be done elsewhere. In the posted code this happens with `sm(SignatureMethod.RSA_PSS, new RSAPSSParameterSpec(pspec))` where `pspec` is of type `PSSParameterSpec` and specifies the PSS parameters.

Comment: Note 8017 (or 3447) A.2 specifies parameters for an actual signature (or encryption); keys are different. 4055 make parameters optional for public key in PKIX, and clarifies that either OID=oldRSA or OID=PSS can be used for PSS signature. IME most things, including Java, follow PKIX rules also for uncertified public keys and (PKCS8) private keys; JCA can generate alg=RSASSA-PSS (OID=PSS) keypair with _or_ without parameters but OP's code does without. OTOH JOSE/JWS/JWE predefines the parameters from the `alg=` name and does not carry them in a key, signature, or encryption.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Some interesting additions. You might want to consider writing your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer how you can use the sun.security module... You can add exports so that you can use the internal API:

In Intellij, you add the sun.security module to the module compiler options.
[image: You can use XmlUtils from the OpenJDK if you add the imports]

Or in Maven:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <release combine.self="override"></release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                        <arg>java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Now you can just copy out the XMLUtils from the OpenJDK project and use it.

@Topaco's answer explains why the self certificate code mentioned here works to sign the certificate using RSA when the alg=RSASSA-PSS.